# Unable to Reference CSS in HTML (python/flask)

Tags: html, css, flask

I am trying to make a simple website using Python and Flask. Right now, I have the HTML and CSS finished, but my page does not show any of the CSS. My files are in the following hierarchy:

```
/static
/static/css/style.css
/static/js/skel.js

/templates
/templates/index.html
```

I have the following code in my html file:

```html
<script src="../static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/config.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>

<noscript>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/skel-noscript.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style-desktop.css" />
</noscript>
```

When I run this, the terminal displays "304" for the JS files and gets them from "/static/js/skel.js" which I think is correct, but it then displays "404" for the CSS files and gets them from "/css/style.css". I am not quite sure why this is happening - shouldn't this be retrieving files from /static/css/style.css? How can I fix it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have un-deleted it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your on-disk layout is *not the same thing* as the routes served by your Flask site. Do not rely on the relative paths between `templates` and `static`.

Instead, have Flask calculate the routes to static files *for you*, using the `url_for()` function in your Jinja template:

```html
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/config.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/skel.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/skel-panels.min.js') }}"></script>

<noscript>    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/skel-noscript.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style-desktop.css') }}" />
</noscript>
```

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you for your help. I just put in the changes you posted, but there appears to be no difference in output. However, when I look at the html file directly on my browser, there are parts of the CSS working. It is not working at all through Flask. Should this be happening? Also, should it be "css/style.css" for the second to last line correct?

Comment: @user2853043: you didn't use `css/` in your post, so I omitted it. It should match the paths inside your `static` folder.

Comment: @user2853043: use your browser developer tools as well as the Flask console log output to debug why the static files are not loading. Look at the generated HTML source to see what URLs are actually generated, try to access those URLs directly, and see what 404 errors Flask is producing for these, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the template is really what you have, and your layout is really what you list, then they don't match:

```
/static/css/style.css
```

does not match

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" />
```

Instead you should have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/style.css" />
```

or move style.css up one folder. Note however that IIRC you can't have `../` in path, because `static` folder is supposed to be at same level as your flask app script. So you should be able to just have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" />
```

but as others have mentioned it is better to have flask generate the url for you via `url_for` (see example in step 6 of tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This solved it:

open your `config.js` and add `static/` in front of the `css/...` in all links like `href="css/style.css"` that they look like `href="static/css/style.css"` and it should be fine.

The question is already 5 months old but I hope I can help someone who has the same problem.